# TTLauncher save items position

Tags: iphone, three20

I am using TTLauncherView and adding items to it dynamically.

My items are added but once I close the application they are not saved.

I am using a plist to save the items.

In my viewDidLoad, I am using this line _launcherView.pages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:array, nil];

to load items on TTLauncherView from plist. But this line is throwing exception.

I would really appreciate if anybody can throw some light on it. May be if someone  can share the code of how to save added items and their changed positions, if they already have succeeded in doind it.

Any help would be appreciated!

I also looked to this links, but no luck!
[dynamically add Items to TTLauncher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681361/three20-dynamically-add-items-to-ttlauncher/5746321#5746321)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old post, so I won't spend too much time here, but if you are already loading your plist successfully, you have (at least) two options: 1) re-save the plist in your documents directory, (making sure to load it from there if it exists), or 2) store your plist data in `NSUserDefaults` when it has been changed (again, checking `NSUserDefaults` before loading the original plist).

Hope you figured this all out long ago.

Comment: I figured out this long ago. I ended up saving everything in core data as I had many TTLauncher items. My app is up and running! Thanks anyways!